# How to replace NULL/? with 'None' or '0' in r

Tags: r, dataframe, null

DF1 is

```
ID CompareID Distance
1  256          0
1  834          0
1  946          0
2  629          0
2  735          1
2  108          1
```

Expected output should be DF2 as below (Condition for generating DF2 -> In DF1, For any ID if 'Distance'==1, put the corresponding 'CompareID' into 'SimilarID' column, for 'Distance'==0, ignore the corresponding 'CompareID')

```
   ID SimilarID
    1  None
    2  735,108
```

Comparison is done correctly , but i got below output

```
   ID SimilarID
    1  ?
    2  735,108
```

I understood that, as there are no 'CompareID' to put in 'SimilarID' - ? mark is displayed.
I want to replace this '?' with 'None' or '0'. Kindly help
In some cases, i observe that instead of '?' i can also see 'NULL' value.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the *data.table* package, where `df` is your original data ...

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(SimilarID = if(all(Distance == 0)) "None" 
              else toString(CompareID[Distance == 1])), by = ID]
#    ID SimilarID
# 1:  1      None
# 2:  2  735, 108
```

This follows your expected output by returning, by `ID`

- `"None"` when all of the `Distance` column is zero
- the `CompareID` values for when `Distance` is 1, as a comma-delimited string

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), CompareID = c(256L, 
834L, 946L, 629L, 735L, 108L), Distance = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L)), .Names = c("ID", "CompareID", "Distance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following using `dplyr`:

```
summarise.func <- function (Distance,CompareID) {
  SimilarID <- CompareID[Distance == 1]
  if (length(SimilarID)==0) "None" else paste0(SimilarID, collapse=",")
}

library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
               summarise(SimilarID=summarise.func(Distance,CompareID))
```

First, define a summarizing function `summarise.func` that:

1. Extracts the `CompareID` to a `SimilarID` vector if the `Distance == 1`.
2. If this `SimilarID` vector has elements, then return a string that are these `CompareID`s collapsed with `","`; otherwise return `"None"`.

Then, use this `summarise.func` to `summarise` `SimilarID` grouped by `ID`.

Using your data:

```
print(df2)
### A tibble: 2 x 2
##     ID SimilarID
##  <int>     <chr>
##1     1      None
##2     2   735,108
```

Comment: You can just use `ifelse`, which is vectorized: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(SimilarID = ifelse(length(CompareID[Distance == 1]) == 0, 'None', toString(CompareID[Distance == 1])))`

Comment: or mutate after the fact: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(SimilarID = toString(CompareID[as.logical(Distance)])) %>% mutate(SimilarID = ifelse(SimilarID == '', 'None', SimilarID))`

Comment: @alistaire: I agree, but I only wanted to do the comparison once (even though it is vectorized). I thought in some sense, this separated my answer from Rich Scriven's (who beat me to the punch by a hair).

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` in base R:

```
df2 <- aggregate((CompareID*Distance)~ID, df, FUN=function(x) 
          ifelse(sum(x)>0, paste(x[x>0], collapse = ","), "None"))

names(df2) <- c("ID", "SimilarID") #if necessary

#  ID SimilarID
#1  1      None
#2  2   735,108
```

`CompareID*Distance` ensures that `CompareID` will be ignored if `Distance==0`. Further, its grouped by `ID`, if `sum` is greater than `0`, the non-zero values (`x[x>0]`) are comma-delimited and `None`, otherwise.

Comment: It's not directly comparing the column data, i have much processing done  done to compare the columns. Sorry for not putting all that code, it involves much RM operations. Simply im searching a way to replace NULL  with any value.